# showing undefined when acessing the html collection by index in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbyclassname

**Javascript**

```
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('preview');
console.log(box[1])
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
    <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>

    <img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

    <img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

    <img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">

</body></html>
```

I just want to get the values of my box[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmeVx.png) or any other index but it shows undefined .

Comment: Hello, Your Code is working fine.

Comment: This can happen because your Javascript should be below your html in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is you have added your js script in the head section of the page. Whenever the page loads the Script is executing first and it is not able to find the class element and returning undefined. You can fix this in two easy ways.

1. Move your script from the head and add it to the end of the body tag. If you don't want to move your script for some reason then follow the second step.
2. Add your JS Code inside this

`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');`
});

When you add your JS code inside this function then your code is executed only when the DOM has loaded means after the HTML elements get loaded.

Check the snippet I have demonstrated the scenario. Remove the above function and add just your js code to see it will return undefined again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
    <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const box = document.getElementsByClassName('preview');
console.log(box[1])
    
    });
   
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>

    <img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()"/>

    <img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()"/>

    <img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()"/>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the HTML elements before the page has finished loading the DOM. Trying moving your `<script src="js/gallery.js"></script>` element to just before the closing `</body>` tag.